# On Samba DCs running on Ubuntu Server 20.04, is DNS resolution handled by by the netplan config or by resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, netplan, resolv.conf, active-directory, samba4

Apologies if this might be a silly question.

I'm reading that best practice when having two DCs in a domain is to point their DNS addresses at each other and also at themselves. So:

DC1 nameservers = DC2, 127.0.0.1
DC2 nameservers = DC1, 127.0.0.1

Now I'm wondering where should this be configured?

At the `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` level, or at `/etc/resolv.conf`? Or both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a silly question at all!  On Ubuntu 18.04 and later, /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to a file managed by systemd-resolved.  One of the ways to provide input to systemd-resolved is via netplan.  So yes, if you want to configure the nameservers for your system, `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` is the simplest way to do it.